# Is Battlefield 3 available as a digital purchase for PC?

Tags: battlefield-3

Is Battlefield 3 available as a digital purchase for PC?

Where can I purchase it online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use EA's Origin store/application to purchase and download Battlefield 3 [here](http://store.origin.com/).

Comment: no longer as "limited edition" unfortunately, so it won't have the Back to Karkand DLC included (available in a month or so) for free.